# How can I change Rstudio command history shortcut?

Tags: r, rstudio

RStudio is amazing, but just one thing annoying me is that I can not modify (presumably) the keyboard shortcut for showing a previous command history.

The default shortcut is up. That is ok, but I would like to add ctrl+p as well, which is used in bash.

I have tried Tools > Modify Keyboard Shortcuts, but can not find 'show command history' in it.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I would also like to change 'show next command history' if possible...

Comment: This guide might be useful https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382178-Customizing-Keyboard-Shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) and map `UP` to `CTRL+p` like this:

Once installed create an `.ahk` file with:

```
^p::
Send {UP}
return
```

I tried it and it works fine.